# Angular 5: Chrome не прикрепляет cессионный куки к запросу?

Tags: c#, angular2, cookie, asp.net-core, httpclient

***1) Делаю запрос на аутентификацию***

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
  console.log(this.apiUrl);
  return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.apiUrl, { UserName: 'someUser', Password: 'somePassword' }, { withCredentials: true } )
  .map(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', 'true');
  });
}
```

***2) Сервер высылает в ответе куки `.AspNet.Session` для сохранения. Проверяю: `Chrome` куки сохраняет:***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***3) Теперь, когда делаю остальные запросы, на подобии этого***

```
getUsers() {
  return this.httpClient.get<User[]>(this.apiUrl, { withCredentials: true });
}
```

***4) Получаю 401 ошибку. И видно, что это из-за того что `Chrome` не прикрепил к запросу необходимый куки `.AspNet.Session`***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**А вот Firefox прикрепляет куки и соответственно запрос проходит успешно. Что это может быть?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте точки в названии куки.

> Cookie name is a sequence of characters excluding semi-colon, comma and white space.

[Источник](https://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html)